# Redirecting from language specific domains to main domain with domain.com/en ending

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have seven domains, that I want to redirect to my main domain with apropriate language ending:

> do-main.de -> do-main.eu/de
>
> do-main.at -> do-main.eu/de
>
> do-main.cz -> do-main.eu/cs
>
> do-main.sk -> do-main.eu/sk
>
> do-main.pl -> do-main.eu/pl
>
> do-main.be -> do-main.eu/nl

and lastly

> domain.eu -> do-main.eu

Here is what i tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://do-main.eu/cz [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(at|de)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://do-main.eu/de [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.sk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://do-main.eu/sk [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://do-main.eu/pl [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://do-main.eu/nl [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.do-main\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.domain\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://do-main.eu [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

but it works only for .de and .at domains (and domain.eu to do-main.eu works too).

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are are these domains pointing to your document root?

Answer (score 1):

You could have following .htaccess Rules file. Please make sure your sub-domains are available and they are pointed to same document root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%do-main.eu%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(do-main)(\.de|at)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.eu/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(do-main)(\.cz)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.eu/cs%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(do-main)(\.sk|pl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.eu/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(do-main)(\.be)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.eu/nl%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```